# Packets sent through TUN interface not routed

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, tunneling

I have a C program attached to a TUN interface.  In this program, I'm building packets and writing them to the interface.

Now to check if packets are really sent from my TUN interface, I use `iptables` rules to log them:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING  -j LOG --log-prefix "PREROUTING-MANGLE "  --log-level 4
iptables -t mangle -A INPUT       -j LOG --log-prefix "INPUT-MANGLE "       --log-level 4
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD     -j LOG --log-prefix "FORWARD-MANGLE "   --log-level 4
```

I can see log messages in the PREROUTING chain, which means packets are correctly sent from the TUN interface. But I can't see packets hit other chains.

I have correctly configured my routing rules and the forwarding option is activated.

Is there any way to log dropped packets or to know the reason why are they dropped?

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: "Not routed" is usually not a firewall problem with locally generated packets. What happens if you disable Netfilter?

Comment: Still the same problem and I need netfilter to filter packets anyway. Don't you know a way to log packets if they're dropped after the routing decision?

Comment: You can check that with the `iptables` target `TRACE`.